# Differences between "Role-Object Pattern" and "Type-Object Patern"

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm studying for university and I have to learn the difference between "Role-Object Pattern" and "Type-Object Patern" (Purpose and Class diagram).

I don't find any difference between them. I believe the class diagram is the same, but the purpose is different (I think). So, I don't understand this last.

How can I realize which of them I have to use?

I'm confused.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is quite off-topic for SO. Look at D18 and D19 on https://riehle.org/computer-science/research/dissertation/appendix-d.html and see if you have a more precise question please

Answer (score 1):

Take these examples for logical mapping of objects.

You have a customer of a bank. Now that customer can be an investor or a borrower. The borrower and the investor have completely different roles, but both are of type customer. This is role based.

On the other hand you have banks. You can have Axis Bank, ICICI Bank etc, with different rates of interest, different credit card options etc. But they all have same functions, just different results for each. This is type based.

The diagram may seem similar, but it's what's common between them that separates them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You were very clear, but now I have another doubt... What about using a "Strategy" instead a "Role-Object"? Is not the same?

Comment: It's like comparing apples with oranges. Strategy relates to choosing algorithms at run time (depending on what kind of data (or object) you receive. A good example would be validators. A validator for a customer object will run different checks as to a validator for investor object. It's a completely different thing.